# sum function not working properly

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, join

My database in SQL Server 2005:

[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRADEFILE
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,SAUDA_DATE) LIKE 'MAR  1 2013%' 
  AND SCRIP_CODE='DLF' AND INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%'
```

This gives me result:

[image]

In this Buy=1 and Sell=2.

If we make sum of Buy Qty i.e. buy_sell=1 then it is 3000

and when we make sum for sell trade qty i.e. buy_sell=2 then it is 3000

But when I fire this query for getting same result as follows:

```
select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,
   SUM(CASE 
        WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='DLF' 
            and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'01/03/2013') 
            and convert(datetime,'06/04/2013') 
        THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='DLF' 
            and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'01/03/2013') 
            and convert(datetime,'06/04/2013') 
        THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='DLF' 
        THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) 
      -SUM(CASE 
           WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='DLF' 
           THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='DLF' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date)
```

It gives me result as:

[image]

i.e. BuyQty=5000 and sellQty is 4000
while we have calculated it as 3000 and 3000 respectively.

How can it be different? is my sum() function working wrong??

Is my query is wrong?

Comment: As a side note you are using `scrip_code='DLF'` in the WHERE and inside each CASE, you can just use it in the WHERE clause and remove it from each CASE, it will simplify your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions are quite different so it is just plausible that the results are too.

Examples:

1. In your first query, you have a condition for `PARTY_CODE`. This is completely missing in the second query.
2. The same goes for `INST_TYPE`
3. The condition for `SAUDA_DATE` is very different. The first query only queries March, 1st, while the second queries everything between March, 1st and April, 6th.

Comment: no, all the records are for same party code only, no issue of party code, i have just checked

Comment: @Freelancer: That still leaves the other issues.

Comment: got it, INST_TYPE wad issue. thanx

Answer (score 1):

I understood that first query you have given, has 3000 for buyin_qty and sell_qty.

In your second query which is having CASE statements misses some of your where condition from First query

```
 AND PARTY_CODE='0L036'
 AND INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%'
```

Comment: INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' was issue, thanx

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
   SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) 
   -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='DLF' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date)
```

Comment: INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' was issue, thanx for taking efforts for me.